# Problemas com cast em reflection

Tags: java, android, reflexão

Boa tarde. Sou novo na utilização da API de reflection java. Estou tendo o seguinte problema, ao tentar criar uma classe de Dao genérica para ser utilizada em um CRUD para sqlite no android, não consigo efetuar um cast de um campo para o tipo correspondente na classe do objeto passado como parâmetro de entrada. Segue o código:

```
public class DaoGenerico<E>{

    private E entrada;
    private Class classe;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private List<Field> campos;
    private List<Method> metodos;
    private String banco;

    public DaoGenerico(E entrada, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        iniciaComponetes(entrada, db);

        if(!classe.isAnnotationPresent(TabelaNoBanco.class)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Classe não pode ser persistida!");
        }

        TabelaNoBanco anotacao = (TabelaNoBanco) classe.getAnnotation(TabelaNoBanco.class);
        this.banco = anotacao.nomeTabela();

    }


    public boolean inserir() throws IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            for (Field f : campos) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Class<?> type = f.getType();

                /*Linha onde deve ser efetuado o cast, porem apresenta erro em type*/
                values.put(f.getName(), (type) f.get(entrada));

            }
            db.insert(banco, null, values);
            db.close();
            return true;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Campo não pode ser convertido");
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Não foi possivel inserir  objeto no banco de dados!");
        }
    }

    private List<Field> obterCampos(){
        return Arrays.asList(classe.getFields());
    }

    private List<Method> obterMetodos(){
        return Arrays.asList(classe.getDeclaredMethods());
    }

    private void iniciaComponetes(E entrada, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.entrada = entrada;
        this.db = db;
        this.classe = entrada.getClass();
        this.campos = obterCampos();
        this.metodos = obterMetodos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o texto exato do erro na pergunta

Comment: Não apresenta erro o próprio android studio sublinha de vermelho como erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro essa linha:

```
private Class classe;
```

Poderia ser:

```
private Class<? extends E> classe;
```

Depois vemos que o seu método `inserir` fecha o objeto `db`, mas não foi ele que abriu. Como boa prática, geralmente a responsabilidade de fechar é de quem abriu. E se o método `inserir` sempre retorna `true`, então qual seria a finalidade do tipo de retorno?

O seu problema ocorre nestas linhas:

```
                Class<?> type = f.getType();

                /*Linha onde deve ser efetuado o cast, porem apresenta erro em type*/
                values.put(f.getName(), (type) f.get(entrada));
```

O que há de errado? É que para fazer um cast você deve utilizar abre-parênteses + nome-de-classe + fecha-parênteses. Ocorre que `type` não é nome de classe, e sim nome de variável. Assim sendo, o compilador não reconhece o cast e dá erro de compilação.

Então como fazer? Pode ser com essa coisa horrorosa:

```
Object obj = f.get(entrada);
if (obj == null) {
    values.putNull(f.getName());
} else if (obj instanceof String) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (String) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Boolean) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Byte) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Byte) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Short) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Short) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Integer) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Long) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Long) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Float) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Float) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Double) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Double) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof Short) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (Short) obj);
} else if (obj instanceof byte[]) {
    values.put(f.getName(), (byte[]) obj);
} else {
    throw new ClassCastException("Campo não pode ser convertido.");
}
```

Ou se quiser usar reflection aqui também:

```
Object obj = f.get(entrada);
if (obj == null) {
    values.putNull(f.getName());
} else {
    Method m;
    try {
        m = ContentValues.class.getMethod("put", String.class, obj.getClass());
        m.invoke(values, f.getName(), obj);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Campo não pode ser convertido.", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Ah, e não se esqueça de usar `campo.setAccessible(true)` e `metodo.setAccessible(true)` onde for pertinente. Caso contrário, você poderá tomar uma `IllegalAccessException`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.